# How to remove beginning of the string separated b delimiter in R?

Tags: r

I have `elephant//giraffe` string and I want to get `giraffe` only splitting it at `//`. How do I remove the beginning of the string separated by the delimiter?

Comment: `sub(".*//", "", "elephant//giraffe")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` function in the following way -

```
x<- "elephant//giraffe"  
unlist(strsplit(x, "//"))[2]

# [1] "giraffe"
```